# Image based WebAR browser framework?

Tags: browser, frameworks, augmented-reality

Is there any free or paid WebAR framework that uses images as markers, and not pattern/barcode markers?
I've only found Awe.js, which has some cons.

Comment: I hope this link works: https://www.facebook.com/augmentmy.world/videos/397716354363800/?__xts__[0]=68.ARChd2ikVNL1xZY2ALv1Hsu36SBEOrP-cIjZw8bNPirZi3R9ycDdg2R6xwKMlKJHlMVZvOnt3grlApf_1mfG_htvL-oKszNfm4C9dXlqfIYH4p_d-83U-HOaovwpL7qHhovyOr8KEgaQpNJ5q0mvDOiJLqCrp4oRAyzy0A4YKDgQUUMVXhiEcbYOfx-SqJCC-YQqlCunQuOvjRKtY6CnX4D_wcPYEGA-qk5YK29kUWMLLvPngAwmm4PO3sYbeSWPr_wHfLWRPj-Cj6CR72Xw5I8MEk7aHdrSzWoscHRvi2-Qimp6letLUVkgJA7lQj4Fij-k6BXnP4hV0flBXk1wTZ-eVSJJSPNMGbg&__tn__=-R

Comment: If you are after something like that, let me know.

Comment: @Thor_Bux that's exactly what I'm looking for. I've been looking through the whole internet. I can't seem to find it on your web page, would you mind sharing more?

Comment: How can I reach you?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is old but probably still shows up in search so I'm answering for anyone looking for solutions.

There are a few different services that offer image marker based tracking: 8th Wall, Blippar, and Zappar. I would say the best option is 8th Wall, their web-based image targets are by far the top in the industry.